# Is it possible to have many systemd services restart with one target?

Tags: systemd

I have many service unit files that I have to restart, and I don't want to have to type them all out. Is it possible to have a single target or service that doesn't know anything about how to launch the other services, but groups them together so they're all restarted with a single command?

How do I write my systemd service unit file or target file if I want to `systemctl restart one-to-rule-them-all`?

Requirements:
1. The uber target wants many other services to be started.
2. The uber target should not know anything about how to start those services.

When I tried this `sudo systemctl restart one-to-rule.target` nothing happens.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/one-to-rule.target
[Unit]
Description=One To Rule Them All
Requires=multi-user.target
Wants=program-api.service  program-gui.service yet-another.service
After=multi-user.target display-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Each of these units `program-api.service` `program-gui.service` `yet-another.service` and `one-to-rule.target` were all enabled, and they all seem to be loaded and active. I can boot the machine, and the services all come up exactly how I want them. However, I just want to type `systemctl restart one-to-rule.target` or something, instead of rebooting.

The dependency graphs look like this

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies one-to-rule.target
one-to-rule.target
● ├─program-api.service
● ├─program-gui.service
● ├─yet-another.service
● └─multi-user.target

$ systemctl list-dependencies --reverse one-to-rule.target
one-to-rule.target
● └─graphical.target
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can work, but each of those .service units must have `PartOf=one-to-rule.target` in order to have restarts propagated to them. (This is actually just a weaker version of `Requires=<…>.target`.)

Unfortunately it is not possible to specify the opposite dependency (ConsistsOf) directly in the target – you need to extend all service files.